# Can not adjust buttons in Tablet Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have tablet layout with displays buttons in 3 rows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Download1"
                android:textColor="#EDFF99"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Download2"
                android:textColor="#EDFF99"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Upload1"
                android:textColor="#EDFF99"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Upload2"
                android:textColor="#EDFF99"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
                <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Download1"
                android:textColor="#EDFF99"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Download2"
                android:textColor="#EDFF99"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayou
```

t>

and its output is like Figure 1. But i want that row number 2 can cover rest of the area and view (Button) display in center of the screen Like Fig 2.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gives you the desired look. Please, try everything before you post on stackoverflow. This was actually very simple.
Here's the screenshot:

[image]

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Download1"
            android:textColor="#EDFF99"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Download2"
            android:textColor="#EDFF99"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Upload1"
            android:textColor="#EDFF99"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
            <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Download1"
            android:textColor="#EDFF99"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Download2"
            android:textColor="#EDFF99"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```